# How do you get the size of a file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io

What is the best way to figure out the size of a file using MATLAB? The first thought that comes to mind is `size(fread(fid))`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Please see the [dir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) function as stated above.

Please note that the dir function works on files and not on directories only.

```
>> s = dir('c:\try.c')

s = 

       name: 'try.c'
       date: '01-Feb-2008 10:45:43'
      bytes: 20
      isdir: 0
    datenum: 7.3344e+005
```

Comment: +1: Good point. I forgot to mention that you can also pass file names.

Comment: And if the file is in your current directory, you can just use `dir('try.c')` without worrying about the path.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) function to get directory information, which includes the sizes of the files in that directory. For example:

```
dirInfo = dir(dirName);  %# Where dirName is the directory name where the
                         %#   file is located
index = strcmp({dirInfo.name},fileName);  %# Where fileName is the name of
                                          %#   the file.
fileSize = dirInfo(index).bytes;  %# The size of the file, in bytes
```

Or, since you are looking for only one file, you can do what [Elazar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849739/matlab-get-file-size/849861#849861) said and just pass an absolute or relative path to your file to DIR:

```
fileInfo = dir('I:\kpe\matlab\temp.m');
fileSize = fileInfo.bytes;
```

Comment: Hey, you earned a badge because of my answer (8>3*2). ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Your answer would have to have at least 10 upvotes, which means mine would have to have 20. I don't think there are enough people on SO who are interested in MATLAB for those sorts of numbers to happen. We can dream though... =)

Answer (score 7):

Use the fact that MatLab has access to Java Objects:

```
myFile = java.io.File('filename_here')
flen = length(myFile)
```

Comment: Always work compare to dir that does not always give an answer.

Comment: I am curious to see where `dir` fails and this succeeds. So far I always got a result with just `dir`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to hardcode in your directory, you can use the built in pwd tool to find the current directory and then add your file name to it. See example below:

```
FileInfo = dir([pwd,'\tempfile.dat'])
FileSize = FileInfo.bytes
```

Comment: Perhaps dir changed over time, but currently you don't need to worry the full name anyway if your file is in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to indicate that `fopen`/`fread`/.. is used. In this case, why not seeking to the end of the file and reading the position?

Example:

```
function file_length = get_file_length(fid)
% extracts file length in bytes from a file opened by fopen
% fid is file handle returned from fopen

% store current seek
current_seek = ftell(fid);
% move to end
fseek(fid, 0, 1);
% read end position
file_length = ftell(fid);
% move to previous position
fseek(fid, current_seek, -1);

end
```

Matlab could have provided a shortcut..

More on `ftell` can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftell.html).

Comment: Thank you.(!) I've found that very useful considering that in my code I have a fileID of an open file to work with, not a file path.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for any file and directory (no need for absolute path) :

```
    dirInfo=dir(pwd);
    index = strcmp({dirInfo.name},[filename, '.ext']); % change the ext to proper extension 
    fileSize = dirInfo(index).bytes
```

Comment: Perhaps dir changed over time, but currently you don't need to worry the full name anyway if your file is in the current directory.

Answer (score -2):

Easy way to find size of file is:
enter these cammands

> > K=imfinfo('filename.formate');
> >
> > size_of_file=K.FileSize

and get size of file.

Comment: Does not appear to work in general. Seems to be designed to work with graphic files only.