# How to avoid error when looping an empty file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a number of files, while some are empty, but when looping until the empty, then it return me the error. How to avoid this case and return 0 when there is nothing in the file.
Here is my code, I want both of the condition to meet, check whether ' A27_data' got inside 'data2', while some of the 'data2' files are empty.

```
data2 = importdata(strcat('f9data\','f7_data', int2str(i)));
feature27_data=(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data2, A27_data)))
```

[image]

Here are my full code, I have do checking for the empty file.

```
data = importdata('DATA/URL/testing_URL')

domain_URL = regexp(data,'\w*://[^/]*','match','once')

[sizeData b] = size(domain_URL);

for i = 1:5

A27_data = domain_URL{i};

s =dir(strcat('f9data\','f7_data', int2str(i)));
if s.bytes == 0
    return 0;
else
    data2 = importdata(strcat('f9data\','f7_data', int2str(i)));
end;

feature27_data=(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data2, A27_data)))

B27(i)=sum(feature27_data)
end

feature27(B27>=10)=1;
feature27(B27<10&B27>5)=0;
feature27(B27<=5)=-1;

feature27'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab quickie: test if text file is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338392/matlab-quickie-test-if-text-file-is-empty)

Comment: I am not going to test if it is empty before reading it, I want the loop still can proceed check to the next file although the first file is empty. Then ignore the empty file, do whatever the file that contains the text. But for now, I get the error when looping until the empty file, and cnt proceed to the rest

Comment: Why do you not want to test if the file is empty before you read it? Just insert an `if`-statement in your `for`-loop. If the file is empty skip it, if not, continue with `importdata`.

Comment: see the edited for my full code, my empty file/s is/are inside the 'f7_data', I have do checking after that. I get the error, any ideas?

Comment: see the edited 2, i have modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338392/matlab-quickie-test-if-text-file-is-empty), how about this:

```
for i = 1:5

    A27_data = domain_URL{i};

    s = dir(strcat('f9data\','f7_data', int2str(i)));

    if s.bytes == 0
        B27(i) = NaN;
    else
        data2 = importdata(strcat('f9data\','f7_data', int2str(i)));
        feature27_data=(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data2, A27_data)));
        B27(i)=sum(feature27_data);

    end
end
```

Before loading any data, check if the file is empty or not. If it is, assign `NaN` to `B27(i)` (or any other default value). If the file actually contains data, run your processing on it.

**Edit**
If you don't like `NaN`, you can do something else, e.g.:

```
B27(i) = 0;
```

**Edit 2**

- Stick with the `B27(i) = NaN` option.
- After the `if`/`else` loop, insert this:

  ```
  if ~isnan(B27(i))
      B27(i) = data2
  end
  ```
- After the `for`-loop, insert this:

  ```
  B27(isnan(B27))=0;
  clear data2
  data2 = B27;
  ```

Comment: now, B27= [NaN     0   NaN   NaN   NaN] and data2=[qwe], i want the data2=[0 qwe 0 0 0], i have prob at data2

Comment: i want when looping until the empty file, the just ignore it with empty array, but still can run for the next iteration, while looping until the file with text then just store the text inside array. But not eliminate the empty file and left over the file with text in array form. i want like 'data2=[0 qwe 0 0 0],'

Comment: but i got mention to ignore the empty files and store the text file in array as above(question), now i get this  B27=[0     0     0     0     0], i cnt run my else statement, i want 'data2=[0 qwe 0 0 0].

Comment: @user3340270 see **Edit 2**

Comment: i have tried, it does not work for me, can u try with my code as above?