# determine if the file is empty and separate them into different file

Tags: matlab

The goal of my code is to look into a certain folder and create a new text file with a list of names of all the files that aren't empty in that folder written to a new file, and the list of names of all the empty files (no text) into another folder. My current code is only able to create a new text file with a list of names of all the files (regardless of its content) written to a new file. I want to know how to set up if statement regarding the content of the file (array).

```
function ListFile
dirName = '';
files = dir(fullfile(dirName,'*.txt'));
files = {files.name};
[fid,msg] = fopen(sprintf('output.txt'),'w+t');
assert(fid>=0,msg)
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',files{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can check out how to determine if a file is empty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2338558/2338750). Are you planning on writing the directory in the `dirName` variable? If so, I suggest taking it as input to the function instead. By the way, I don't think the `sprintf` serves any purpose here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** The linked solution in [Stewie Griffin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269862/determine-if-the-file-is-empty-and-separate-them-into-different-file/56270162#comment99155069_56269862) is way better. Use this!

---

A simple approach would be to iterate all files, open them, and check their content. Caveat: If you have large files, this approach might be memory intensive.

A possible code for that could look like this:

```matlab
function ListFile
  dirName = '';
  files = dir(fullfile(dirName, '*.txt'));
  files = {files.name};

  fidEmpty = fopen(sprintf('output_empty_files.txt'), 'w+t');
  fidNonempty = fopen(sprintf('output_nonempty_files.txt'), 'w+t');

  for iFile = 1:numel(files)
    content = fileread(files{iFile})
    if (isempty(content))
      fprintf(fidEmpty, '%s\n', files{iFile});
    else
      fprintf(fidNonempty, '%s\n', files{iFile});
    end
  end

  fclose(fidEmpty);
  fclose(fidNonempty);
```

I have two non-empty files `nonempty1.txt` and `nonempty2.txt` as well as two empty files `empty1.txt` and `empty2.txt`. Running this code, I get the following outputs.

Debugging output from `fileread`:

```matlab
content =
content =
content = Test
content = Another test
```

Content of `output_empty_files.txt`:

```
empty1.txt
empty2.txt
```

Content of `output_nonempty_files.txt`:

```
nonempty1.txt
nonempty2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab isn't really the optimal tool for this task (although it is capable).  To generate the files you're looking for, a command line tool would be much more efficient.

For example, using GNU find you could do

```
find . -type f -not -empty -ls > notemptyfiles.txt
find . -type f -empty -ls > emptyfiles.txt
```

to create the text files you desire.  [Here's a link](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-files-with-zero-size/) for doing something comparable using the windows command line.  You could also call these functions from within Matlab if you want to using the [system command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html).  This would be much faster than iterating over the files from within Matlab.