# check the size of a file MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to check the size of file

is it correct if I use

```
aux = dir(diary_file);
sizeOfFile = aux.bytes;

bytes: 362
```

now I would like to check that the size of file is >1 , how could I do it

Comment: possibly duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849739/how-do-you-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-matlab

Comment: @shakthydoss: not a duplicate -- s/he's asking how to check if a variable > 1. I'm closing because there does not seem to be a minimal understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something here, it's pretty straightforward:

```
if sizeOfFile > 1
   disp('Size of file is greater than 1'); % or do whatever else you want in that case
else
   disp('Size of file is less or equal to 1'); % or do whatever else you want in that case
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to have some fun, here's a slightly more idiot-proof version:

```
try 
    aux = dir(diary_file);
catch ME
    ME2 = MException('insert:id', 'Could not get directory listing for file/dir:');
    throw(addCause(ME2, ME));
end

if ~isempty(aux) 

    if numel(aux) == 1
        sz = aux.bytes;
    elseif aux.isdir
        error('insert:id', 'Expected single file; got directory listing.');
    else
        error('insert:id', 'Inconsistent directory listing.');
    end

    if ispc
        [~,~,ext] = fileparts(aux.name);
        if strcmpi(ext, '.lnk')
            warning('insert:id', ...
               'File seems to be a link; size may be misrepresented.'); 
        end
    end

    if sz > 1
        % CHECK PASSED
    else
        % CHECK NOT PASSED
    end

else
    error('insert:id', 'File does not exist.');
end
```